# Is it possible to add an exception with a "ls -l *"

Tags: linux, bash, unix, shell, script

Is it possible to do for exemple: `ls -l *` which print the content of all a directory.
And add an exception, for exemple, `test.cpp`
In order to print all files except the `test.cpp`.

Comment: --hide or --ignore from the man page should work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with a glob if you have `extglob` enabled. You can enable it with:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

And you can use it like:

```
ls -l !(test.cpp)
```

and it can be used in other ways, too:

```
ls -l !(*.jpg) # list all files that don't have .jpg extensions
```

Since this is a shell glob it can be used with other commands as well. One side effect, however, is that it causes any subdirectories to be listed explicitly, which means that `ls` would list them too. But, that can easily be handled with:

```
ls -ld !(test.cpp)
```

Answer (score 2):

The classic (naive?) way to do this would be

```
  ls -l * | grep -v test.cpp
```

However, as Lamar commented, GNU `ls` has options for ignoring certain filenames

```
  ls -l -I test.cpp *
```

Note `ls -l *` lists files in the current directory *and files in 1st level subdirectories*. You may have meant `ls -l` without the `*`

Comment: Or maybe `ls -ld *`.